# Javascript - Jquery shows only the first data in every case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a third data on my bootstrap modal. If a customer select 2 datas, it shows the relations between the 2 section. I used Jquery for it. It actually worked, but when I open the modal, it just show the first user in every case. I store the datas in MySQL, and the users also. So if I select Computer1 and Computer4, I want to print User1 and User4.

### HTML

```js
$(function() {
            // cache jQuery objects that we will be re-using
            var checkBoxes = $("input[name=case]");
            var myModal = $("#myModal");
            var user=checkBoxes.data("user");
            
            // get all relationships i.e. key = name, value = connect or null
            var relations = {};
            checkBoxes.each(function() {
                relations[this.dataset.name] = this.dataset.connect;
            });

            $('#checkBtn').click(function() {
                // get checked checkboxes
                var checkedBoxes = checkBoxes.filter(":checked");

                // validate first
                if (checkedBoxes.length !== 2) {
                    alert("You must check 2 checkbox!");
                    return false;
                }

                // build modal body
                var html = "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-bordered'><tr><td align='center'><b>Name</b></td><td align='center'><b>Connect to</b></td><td align='center'><b>User</b></td></tr>";
    
                var current = checkedBoxes[0].dataset.name, // start with
                end = checkedBoxes[1].dataset.name; // end with
               
                while (current) {
                    html +="<tr><td>"+current+"</td>";

                    // check if it is connected
                    var next = relations[current];

                    // if it is not connected, stop
                    if (!next) {
                        html = 'Not related';
                        break;
                    }

                    // otherwise append HTML
                    html +="<td>"+next+"</td><td>"+user+"</td></tr>";
                    
                    // if it is the end, stop
                    if (next === end) break;

                    // start over using connected one
                    current = next;
                }
                
                html+="</table></div>";
                
                // update modal
                myModal.find('.modal-body').html(html);

                // open the modal dynamically once it is ready
                myModal.modal('show');
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Checkboxes -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Connect to</th>
            <th>Users</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="case" data-name="Computer1" data-connect="Computer3" data-user="User1"></td>
            <td>Computer1</td>
            <td>Computer3</td>
            <td>User1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="case" data-name="Computer2" data-connect="Computer3" data-user="User2"></td>
            <td>Computer2</td>
            <td>Computer3</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="case" data-name="Computer3" data-connect="Computer4" data-user="User3"></td>
            <td>Computer3</td>
            <td>Computer4</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="case" data-name="Computer4" data-user="User4"></td>
            <td>Computer4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>User4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Input button -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="button" id="checkBtn" value="View" class="btn btn-info">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modaldata">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like relations, handle users as well.

Culprit is below line, it gives user data of first checkbox.

`var user=checkBoxes.data("user");`

```js
$(function() {
            // cache jQuery objects that we will be re-using
            var checkBoxes = $("input[name=case]");
            var myModal = $("#myModal");
            
            // get all relationships i.e. key = name, value = connect or null
            var relations = {}, users = {};
            checkBoxes.each(function() {
                relations[this.dataset.name] = this.dataset.connect;
                users[this.dataset.name] = this.dataset.user;
            });

            $('#checkBtn').click(function() {
                // get checked checkboxes
                var checkedBoxes = checkBoxes.filter(":checked");

                // validate first
                if (checkedBoxes.length !== 2) {
                    alert("You must check 2 checkbox!");
                    return false;
                }

                // build modal body
                var html = "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-bordered'><tr><td align='center'><b>Name</b></td><td align='center'><b>Connect to</b></td><td align='center'><b>User</b></td></tr>";
    
                var current = checkedBoxes[0].dataset.name, // start with
                end = checkedBoxes[1].dataset.name; // end with
               
                while (current) {
                    html +="<tr><td>"+current+"</td>";

                    // check if it is connected
                    var next = relations[current];

                    // if it is not connected, stop
                    if (!next) {
                        html = 'Not related';
                        break;
                    }

                    // otherwise append HTML
                    html +="<td>"+next+"</td><td>"+users[current]+"</td></tr>";
                    
                    // if it is the end, stop
                    if (next === end) break;

                    // start over using connected one
                    current = next;
                }
                
                html+="</table></div>";
                
                // update modal
                myModal.find('.modal-body').html(html);

                // open the modal dynamically once it is ready
                myModal.modal('show');
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Checkboxes -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Connect to</th>
            <th>Users</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="case" data-name="Computer1" data-connect="Computer3" data-user="User1"></td>
            <td>Computer1</td>
            <td>Computer3</td>
            <td>User1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="case" data-name="Computer2" data-connect="Computer3" data-user="User2"></td>
            <td>Computer2</td>
            <td>Computer3</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="case" data-name="Computer3" data-connect="Computer4" data-user="User3"></td>
            <td>Computer3</td>
            <td>Computer4</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="case" data-name="Computer4" data-user="User4"></td>
            <td>Computer4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>User4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Input button -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="button" id="checkBtn" value="View" class="btn btn-info">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modaldata">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```